# Passing ampersand from JavaScript to PHP/MySQL

Tags: javascript, ampersand

I have a textarea which I'm using JavaScript to retrieve the value of and send to a MySQL database via a PHP script (don't ask why - long story and an unavoidable resolution!).

The PHP script sanitizes the input, but for some reason ampersands aren't ever reaching the said script - it also culls any information after the ampersand.

```
var Reason = $('textarea#txt_reason').val();
Reason = Reason.replace(/&/g,'&amp;');
```

If I use the above, all text after the ampersand is culled.

```
var Reason = $('textarea#txt_reason').val();
Reason = Reason.replace(/&/g,'%26');
```

If I use the above, the %26 does indeed get sent through to PHP and thus the MySQL database.

If I `var_dump` the $_GET request in the PHP script, the ampersands never get that far so it isn't anything to do with mysql_real_escape_string/htmlentities etc.

Is there a way I can directly send "&" to my PHP script, without having to encode/decode?

Cheers,
Duncan

Comment: Can you post the code you're using to send `Reason` to the php script?

Comment: You could just use the built in Javascript function `encode(str)`. I'm not too familiar with PHP, but ***usually*** anything retrieving values from http query string should automatically decode encoded elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any data that you send using Javascript should be encoded with `encodeURIComponent()`.  This will take care of the &, =, and other troublemakers.  The data is automatically decoded into the $_GET array.

(Most Javascript frameworks such as JQuery do this for you...)

Comment: I think therein lies the problem: the framework/API I'm using doesn't deal with the ampersand properly. Thanks!